# Link Private Apple Framework with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, dependency-management, iphone-privateapi

*Disclaimer: I am working on a library that is linked to a Non-App Store project via CocoaPods. The library uses private API's for multiple functionalities. I'm just asking for a technical solution.*

I am working on a library that is redistributed using CocoaPods. In the core project of the library I am linking it with one of the private frameworks shipped with Xcode. The exact location of the framework is:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks
```

I would like to avoid copying this framework into the library to be linked as "CocoaPods Private Framework" and rather link it directly according to the iOS SDK choosen in the **Xcode project** or **Podfile**.

So my question is:

**Does CocoaPods support linking against Apple's private frameworks shipped with Xcode? If yes, what is the correct syntax to specify the framework in `.podspec` file?**

I have not been able to find any exact information about this on the web, only for linking specific frameworks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite some time passed, but since I was looking for the same thing and ended up here there might be other hits, too.
So, the answer is adding the following to your spec file:

```
  s.xcconfig     =  { "FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS" => "$(SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DIR)/PrivateFrameworks" }
```